# Cannot use GoToDate in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to use the method `gotoDate` available [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/gotoDate), so I did:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
  locale: 'it',
  header: {
    left: 'prev, next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'list'
  },
  height: 500,
  defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
  navLinks: true, 
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true
});

calendar.render();
```

when I use the function:

```
calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment());
```

I get:

> fullCalendar is not a function

Comment: The documentation link you've shown is for fullcalendar version 3. But the rest of your code is for version 4. Make sure you read the correct documentation version. The version 4 documentation is at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-gotoDate . `calendar.gotoDate( new Date() )` (or `calendar.gotoDate( moment() )` if you prefer to use momentJS) would solve your issue (assuming that `calendar` is in scope in the place where you are using it).

Answer (score 0):

In FullCalendar v4, the method you used is removed, that is why you cannot use the approach which was in v3.

For v4, use [This Link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-gotoDate).

> calendar.gotoDate( date )

Comment: momentJS is not the main problem here, the syntax of the function call is...but you haven't mentioned that at all. MomentJS could still be used for that part, if the OP wants - there is nothing stopping it being included in the page, and, fullcalendar 4 still has a way to integrate moment, via a plugin.

Comment: Boss, thats true, we can use momentJS. The OP is using old syntax for 'gotoDate' with moment. The new syntax I mentioned in my answer :)

Comment: Yes you mentioned the new syntax, but the description you give of the reason for the problem doesn't mention it. So the description and the code solution don't agree with each other :-)

Comment: Well, as MomentJS is officially removed from V4, bcoz of that the old approach cannot be used as that method is removed too. What else should I have mentioned boss !?

Comment: You should mention more clearly why `calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate'` is the wrong syntax. P.S. I'm not saying that using `moment()` isn't a problem, I'm just saying it's not the only / main reason for the failure.